# iOS: Incorrect/Repetitive Facebook Request Message

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using the Facebook SDK and [Parse](http://www.parse.com).

I am submitting additional requests for the users email, events, and their friends' events.

Although I receive this info successfully, users who are logged into iOS' facebook system get this popup when I request permissions.

[image: FB popup]

Notice that they are already logged into facebook (via the settings app) and they are simply getting a message to approve the request.

As you can see, it repeats the info about basic profile and friend list (FB login gives you this by default) and doesn't even mention the email. Since I doubt Apple or FB has made this kind of mistake, I assume it has something to do with me. Here is how I request access using  FB and Parse.

```
    // The permissions requested from the user
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"email, user_events, friends_events"];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

        if (!user) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);

            }
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
            [self.delegate ViewWasDismissed];
            [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            [self.delegate ViewWasDismissed];
            [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
```

again, this request WORKS. Therefore, I can't imagine what I could be doing wrong, but the message is strange. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I tried deleting my account from the iOS facebook system and requesting directly through the app. This time I got this message:

[image: successImage]

Notice that here, the user is logged into facebook via the FB app and simply gets this (correct) message to accept permissions.

Is this some kindof bug with Apple's Facebook system?

Comment: in-sort what's actually issue...? your issue is that u are getting permission window again n again...?

Comment: take a look at the actual text of the permission window. It mentions "basic profile info and list of friends" twice. I'm assuming thats not supposed to happen.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying that you are getting wrong alert message when you already logged on facebook? And if you are loggin in from app you are getting right message?

Comment: iOS allows me to be constantly logged into FB via the settings app. Alternatively, if I have disabled this, I can log in via the FB app. In either case, when my app requests permissions, it asks me to accept those permissions. In the first case, the permission request message is wrong, while in the second case it is correct.

Comment: I updated the question to try and clarify that further

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. "basic profile info" includes the user's email address. If you believe the message to be misleading file a radar with Apple.

Comment: "[The app] would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends. In addition it would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends...". That's definitely not correct behavior. It's just repeating itself!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behaviour that will happened for iOS. Since iOS 6, Apple has integrated Facebook to the devices. Therefore, users can log in Facebook from Settings page. Below are the scenario that explain your confusions.

**Scenario 1: Logged in to Facebook from Settings page**

The app will automatically detect the Facebook account from your device if there's any, and prompt you the permissions request with UIAlertView. This only happen if you're using latest SDK and I am not so sure since which SDK that Facebook released for iOS has this.

**Scenario 2: Not logged in to Facebook from Settings page (Old way)**

The app will lead you to Facebook app if it's installed in your device. Else it will lead you to Safari with Facebook mobile page open and ask you for permissions that the app required.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is that in the Scenario 1 example (see first screenshot above), the request message repeats itself like a bad typo. Is that due to an SDK mismatch of some sort?

Comment: @USS1994 The first screenshot = Scenario 1 and you couldn't change the wordings cause its generated according to the permissions that you requested.

Comment: I understand that it's auto-generated, but why is it mentioning "basic profile info and list of friends" twice? I didn't request it two times (and it shouldn't matter even if I had).